# Exchange 2010 - Exchange MAPI connection problem

Tags: mapi, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, rdo, outlook-redemption

I have a software solution for Exchange 2000/2003/2007 and now hopefully after this for 2010. The software runs on the server and uses Exchange MAPI through [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) to talk the the exchange server, retrieving emails inside mailboxes.

All works fine on Exchange 2000/2003/2007 but 2010 just won't budge. Keep on getting this error when trying to access a mailbox (in call to Session.getSharedMailbox - RDO lib):

```
10:35:31:865       11932    Error in   IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore(pbExchangeProviderPrimaryUserGuid): MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER
ulVersion: 0
Error: The Microsoft Exchange Server computer is not available.  Either there are network problems or the Microsoft Exchange Server computer is down for maintenance.
Component: Microsoft Exchange Server Information Store
ulLowLevelError: 0
ulContext: 1318 (MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER)
```

From the error it seems like the exchange server is down, but its not, I can access everything fine from outlook.
I've presented my case with the developer of RDO and we are still in correspondence, but I was just thinking this may be some new Exchange 2010 feature or architectural change or MAPI change that may cause this? Is there something I need to configure besides enabling MAPI on the mailboxes and giving access to the account that the software is running as?

Anyone ever ran into something similar? Any help will really be appreciated.

**Edit:** If I install outlook on this machine (thus replacing Exchange MAPI with Outlook MAPI) all works fine, which tells me the problem is Exchange MAPI? Any MS Exchange Devs on SO?

Comment: In previous versions of Exchange, MAPI calls were made directly to the Mailbox Server/Back End.  This is not the case in Exchange 2010, everything is made to the Client Access Server and must be proxied via RPCClientAccessService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to set the following registry key to 1:

***SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem\CDO\Ignore No PF***

Refer to [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffga/archive/2007/08/07/cdo-changes-to-work-better-when-accessing-mixed-exchange-2003-2007-servers.aspx) for more details